# Best Framework for RPG/RTS Platform Dev?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, cocos2d-iphone

Just starting off on iPhone development and I'm looking for some input as to the best platform/framework upon which to build at the moment.  I've looked at various options a year or so ago such as cocos2d, unity, and others, however I'm looking for some more current input from those in the trenches.

I am starting on an RTS Diablo-esque game and would like to understand what the highest recommendations at the moment may be with the most robust APIs, etc. for iPhone/iPad development.  In addition, as a plus but not required, it would be nice to understand how portable the platform would be to the desktop.  Bonus++: portable to other mobile devices?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nowadays we have cocos3D still beta, but maybe worth check it out.
http://maniacdev.com/2011/02/open-source-cocos3d-take-cocos2d-apps-to-another-dimension/

Answer (score 1):

[Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) because you can incorporate [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) map editor into your game making RPG/RTS design (relatively) easy. But, that's just my opinion you can do it however you want technically. And just going to the site now it seems they have released a version of Cocos2d that will work on the Mac too.

Comment: There is also a cocos2d port for android. I don't know if it has feature parity yet.

Comment: Very good remarks, thanks for the updates on cocos2d.  Are there any readily integrateable 3D libs that tie in nicely with cocos2d, or would the stock opengl implementation from  work out best when tying in some 3D to an app?

Comment: @ylluminate: I do not know much about 3D. I would go with the OpenGL ES route for it... but others have tried Unity and stuff. I don't think there is any easy way to port 3D into Cocos2D without trying to do stuff like OpenGL ES (hence it's cocos*2d* not cocos3d).

Comment: @thyrgle: Right, that is what I fear.  I am, though, wondering about taking a c or c++ lib and porting it over to interface with cocos2d.  It seems that perhaps that might facilitate proper integration and allow for a cocos2d+3d ability.  Not sure how necessary it would be at this time, but it seems interesting nonetheless.